# How can i get a larger area of pixels for the Robot.getPixelColor(x, y) method?

Tags: java

My current code, pasted below, will obviously only get the color of the pixels(x, y) `1,1`,        `2, 2`, `3,3` and so on until it finds a color with the same RGB values as `targetColor` and if it doesn't find a match stop at `1000,1000` pixels. What is a better way of doing this, so i am not only getting the colors of the pixel co-ordiantes `1,1`, `2,2` and so on. ?

AND I need to use the `getPixelColor(x, y)` method, because I need the co-ordiantes of the color, so I can click the color location.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Robot;

public class Colour
{
    int    x, y;
    int    n    = 0;
    int    m    = 0;
    int    i    = 0;

    public Colour()
    {
        try
        {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            Color targetColor = new Color(255, 25, 255);
            Color color = robot.getPixelColor(n, n);

            while (color.getRGB() != targetColor.getRGB() && i != 1000)
            {
                color = robot.getPixelColor(n, n);
                System.out.println("color = " + color);
                n++;
                i++;

                if (color.getRGB() == targetColor.getRGB())
                {
                    i = 1000;
                    System.out.println("colour found" + n + " " + n);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Colour color = new Colour();
    }
}
```

If I was not clear in what i asked, just say and i will try to explain in more depth or a more understandable way.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably capture a larger area at once, using [Robot.createScreenCapture(Rectangle screenRect)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29).

This will return a `BufferedImage`, so you can use any of the normal techniques to analyse the specific pixels in the BufferedImage. A BufferedImage is basically an in-memory representation of an image that is a convenient form to examine and maniplate via code.

If you are doing a lot of processing at once, it make make sense to convert the BufferedImage to an int[] array of ARGB values.

Comment: how would i do this? i have never worked with BufferedImage before or used the createScreenCapture method. i may need to look at some javadocs lessons, but thanks for the idea, i will follow it up

Answer (score 0):

To access all the Pixels from (0,0) to (1000,1000) try using this:

```
for(int i=0;i<=1000;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<=1000;j++){
        color = robot.getPixelColor(i, j);
        System.out.println("color = " + color);

        if(color.getRGB() == targetColor.getRGB()){
            System.out.println("colour found" + i + " " + j);
            i=1000;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Replace the while-loop with this and you should be fine.

Comment: but i and j will both intcrease by one each loop so they will be the same up to 1000? i think

Comment: No, j will increase each loop, and when j reaches 1000, i will increase by one and j will reset to 0.